# Issue with Lollipop (Android version 5.0.2) on Moto G: unable to pick calls.

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g2

After upgrading to Android Lollipop, I am unable to pick calls though the phone plays the ringtone for incoming calls and shows the call as 'missed' later. It does show anything on screen by which I can pick the call. Kindly help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to check is in

Settings > Sound & notification > Interruptions

that Calls is switched on to allow dialer to bring up the notification window... Then you should get the popup to answer the phone. Good luck though - if your phone is like mine (a Motorola G 2nd gen) depending on what your doing on the phone at the time of the call the stupid call/reject slider doesn't work... WTF - Phones that can't answer phone calls - FAIL!

Answer (score 0):

Under Settings > Sim cards > Check your Connection priority. There is an option to set to "Voice" or "Data".

You must select "Voice".